# Rails - How to Average Columns where reviewed_id = user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have an app where users are reviewed by other users base on different characteristics.

Right now I'm getting the average of a column (let's say the column is "smart" and its an integer)

But the problem is I'm pulling up the average of "smart" for all the users.
I want it to be the average of "smart" of the user I am viewing.

Here is my code right now:
Users Controller:

```
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     @smart = Review.average(:smart)
```

User Show View:

```
<%=@smart%>
```

Comment: Can you go more in depth on the `average` scope?

Comment: @MattLeonard: `average` is not a scope, `average` is a standard ActiveRecord method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [fine **Active Record Query Interface** guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#calculations):

> **9 Calculations**
>   [...]
>   All calculation methods work directly on a model:
>
> ```
> Client.count
> # SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM clients
> ```
>
> Or on a relation:
>
> ```
> Client.where(first_name: 'Ryan').count
> # SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM clients WHERE (first_name = 'Ryan')
> ```

Note the *on a relation* example.

If you want to compute an average on a subset of the columns then say so:

```
@smart = Review.where(:user_id => params[:id]).average(:smart)
```

or even:

```
@smart = @user.reviews.average(:smart)
```

if you have the associations set up.

Comment: Thank you! The first line of code worked, while the second one didn't. I thought I had my associations setup but I guess I don't have them setup right.

Comment: Is there a better way to handle the logic in my controller than `@kind = Review.where(:reviewed_id => params[:id]).average(:kind)
   @honest = Review.where(:reviewed_id => params[:id]).average(:honest)
   @genuine = Review.where(:reviewed_id => params[:id]).average(:genuine)
   @fun = Review.where(:reviewed_id => params[:id]).average(:fun)
   @smart = Review.where(:reviewed_id => params[:id]).average(:smart)
   @cool = Review.where(:reviewed_id => params[:id]).average(:cool)`

Comment: It seems unefficient and repetitive

Comment: I think you'd be stuck with `Review.where(...).select('avg(kind) as k, avg(honest) as h, ...')` to do that.

Comment: that doesnt look too much better i suppose. thanks for the help i appreciate it.

Comment: You can hide that behind a class method (that would return a Hash presumably) easily enough if you don't want to look at the ugliness all the time.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll look into that.  This may seem funny, but how do you get the average of the averages? I'm trying to give users an overall score that takes the average of all of their characteristics

Comment: The same way you calculate any other average: add them up and divide by the number of items. You'll probably get strings out of the `select('avg...')` approach so you might want to add some `to_f` calls to get numbers.